# error: app/org.gimp.GIMP/x86_64/master not installed

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, flatpak

When running

```
flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP
```

I get.

```
error: app/org.gimp.GIMP/x86_64/master not installed
```

I want to run gimp without splash screen

```
 flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP -s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/gimp_gimp.desktop /snap/bin/gimp -s %U
```

The -s starts Gimp without a splash screen and starts a little faster.